# app label not updating after copying project

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a new project by copying and renaming an existing android project in eclipse. I also updated the string value for "app_name" in strings.xml to the new app name. I also updated the android:label in my new project's manifest file to the new app name. However when I install my new project on my phone for testing then I still see the app name as the old project app name. Though the icon shown is the new one I had created for the new project.  I even deleted the android:label entry from my manifest file and still the app gets installed with the label name of the old project. Can anyone suggest what could be goign wrong here? Thanks

Added manifest file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bfp.pkg1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/Theme" 
    android:label="My New Label">
    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.pkg1.FirstActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_first"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.pkg1.SettingHomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:parentActivityName="com.bfp.easylena.FirstActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.bfp.pkg1.FirstActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.pkg1.RunQuizActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.pkg1.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.pkg1.MyAccountActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my_account" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bfp.pkg1.BrowsePrivateActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_browse_private" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix it. My Main activity label, as specified in the manifest file, was overriding the app label. Taking that out fixed the issue.